# Apply Function to every row of the column df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to calculate Euclidean distance for every row of the column. Euclidean distance calculates distance between two coordinates.

```
def measure_distance(x,y):
    p1 = np.array([651700.453,4767830.552])
    p2 = np.array([651701.446,4767831.971])
    d=np.linalg.norm(p2-p1)

df['Desired Output/Distance between coords'] = df.apply(lambda row : add(measure_distance['A'], axis = 1)
```

Doesn't seem to work

I want to apply above function to df

```
Coordinate  Coordinate     Desired Output/Distance between coords
    x           y   
651243.933  4766822.602 
651258.583  4766826.795    15.23823313
651261.454  4766827.617    2.986356476
651266.262  4766828.988    7.986005885
651269.14   4766829.809    2.992812223
651285.448  4766834.461    16.95853673
651298.459  4766838.172    13.5298796
651329.205  4766846.942    31.97232266
651334.422  4766848.43     5.425056037
```

Comment: Your `measure_distance` doesn't use `x` nor `y`, and returns `None`. And since it's a function, `measure_distance["A"]` would raise an error. Have you actually run your code?

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" isn't a valid problem statement. It just tells me that you are asking someone to solve this without bothering to look at the debugging info in front of you.

Comment: Please consider providing debugging output like stack traces or incorrevt results as part of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert 'x' and 'y' to an array '[x, y]' then shift to compute the difference. Finally, apply the norm:

```
out = df[['x', 'y']].apply(np.array, axis=1)
df['dist'] = out.sub(out.shift()).apply(np.linalg.norm)

# OR (without intermediate variable)

df['dist'] = df[['x', 'y']].sub(df[['x', 'y']].shift()) \
                           .apply(tuple, axis=1).apply(np.linalg.norm)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
            x            y       dist
0  651243.933  4766822.602        NaN
1  651258.583  4766826.795  15.238233
2  651261.454  4766827.617   2.986356
3  651266.262  4766828.988   4.999650
4  651269.140  4766829.809   2.992812
5  651285.448  4766834.461  16.958537
6  651298.459  4766838.172  13.529880
7  651329.205  4766846.942  31.972323
8  651334.422  4766848.430   5.425056
```